# I have a "big" database, what RDBMS/design should I use?

Tags: discussion

There are several instances of this type of question lurking around.  The answers are invariably opinionated, irrelevant, and in some cases intentionally misrepresentative or just plain wrong.
Should these kinds of questions be encouraged?  My instinct is to downvote them on the basis that the answers are primarily opinions.

Example of a better one: [Database/Storage engine suggestion for a project involving heavy inserts?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/database-storage-engine-suggestion-for-a-project-involving-heavy-inserts)

Or this: [Suggestion for Large SQL Server Database Design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/suggestion-for-large-sql-server-database-design?rq=1)

Comment: I would close them. It's like asking, "I have a big family, what car should I buy?"

Comment: Yes, please vote-to-close. Down-voting is for bad questions, not off-topic ones.